# Firebase Realtime Database Allow read/write if string matches an attribute

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

My firebase realtime database structure:

```
stores
   -store1234
      -data
      -specialKeyForStore1234
   -store4567
      -data
      -specialKeyForStore4567
   -...
```

My goal:

-**data** should be public readable for everyone, but only the store that owns the data should be able to add/edit/remove the data

Now in my webapp there is **no sign-in authentication** required to access the database, but to restricts others to change other stores data, I would like to implement something like this:

If **store1234** wants to write/edit its own *data*, it needs to provide this **specialKeyForStore1234**.

The actual webapp of **store1234** has this special key and can compare the value with the one from database to match, if there is a match, then let access for read and write. Otherwise refuse it.

How can it be done?

Comment: Is it a legacy database or are you in the process of developing it?

Comment: process of developing

Comment: Two options: (a) Add the secret to the request parameter and handle that in the security rules. (b) Have two databases, one database for writing with the secret being a part of the the path `store1234/specialKeyForStore4567/...` and guarded by simple security rules. The other database open for reading to everyone. Then, sync the database-for-writing via Cloud Functions with the database-for-reading.

Comment: How would I do option (a)? Like I have statements like:
`var newProductRef = db.ref('stores/'+id+'/products').push();
            let newProductData = { ... };
            newProductRef.set(newProductData);`
`
i have the specialKey variable there, but don't know how to tell firebase to only let pass the set() call if the specialKey is set and is a correct set specialKey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send the special key, add a field `specialKey` to the model.

Basically, check that the model-key `specialKey` is equal to the database-field `specialKey`.

The obvious problem with this approach is, that the `specialKey` of the model is then persisted with every object, there is a suggestion for that below, too.

Note: `newData` is the incoming model-data.

The code below might point in the right direction. I did not test it and might have made wrong assumptions.

**Rule**

```json
{
  "rules": {
     "shops": {
       "$shop_id" {
            "payload" {
                ".read":  if true,

                 // OPTION A                 

                ".write": "root.child(shops).child($shop_id)
                  .child(newData.child('specialKey)).exists()"
                
                // OPTION B
                // 
                // Try deleting the secrectKet in the model.
                // No idea if this works in real life.
                // === seems to be correct for assigning values?
                
                ".write": "root.child(shops).child($shop_id)
                  .child(newData.child('specialKey)).exists() 
                  && newData.child('specialKey).val() === '' "
                
            },
            "specialKey" {
                // is READ:false ok to be processed by rule above?
                ".read":  if false, 
                ".write": if false,
            }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

**Data Structure**

```json
{
    "shops": {
        "shop-a": {
            "payload": "yourPayload",
            "SuperSecretSpecialKey123": true
       }
    }
}
```

**Source**

https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language#building_conditions

**Bottom Line**

It might be worth considering a normal authentication process, then one could assign users write-roles and user proper authentication.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer and this [firebase api link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database) helped me to understand how these rules work. 

Altough I think the idea I had with this key doesn't work/scale like I thought. When I want to remove an item, it doesn't let me because the remove() command doesn't let me to pass on parameters. Since there is no custom permission for ".delete" I am stuck here and need to think of another approach, probably with anonym auth.